# Clear table shading in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

I have a document with 137 tables all shaded a horrible blue and 3D style that makes them take up too much space.

How do I at least get rid of the shading on them all *at the same time*?

It would be nice to know how to edit them all to get rid of the extraneous styling and make them simple lined tables that autofit contents but I know that's a lot to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run this VBA as a macro to remove the shading and change the table style to normal borders;

```
Sub RemoveShading()

    Dim tbl As Table
    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        tbl.Shading.Texture = wdTextureNone
        tbl.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
        tbl.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
        tbl.Style = "Table Grid"
    Next

End Sub
```

*Note: I tested this in Word 2010 with tables built from the standard tool bars.*

Edit by OP:

- To create this macro, go to File, Options, Customize Ribbon
- Check the "Developer" box under "Main Tabs" under "Customize the Ribbon" on the right.
- Click "OK"
- On the Developer ribbon, click Macros
- Name a new macro, edit it, copy paste in the code in the VBA window that pops up, save and close.
- Click macro's again in word and run your fancy new macro

Comment: If I could upvote this twice I would. That worked perfectly and was a great starting point to add my own custom formatting. I'm editing this answer to add simple instructions on how to get the macro created.

Comment: Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

**To remove the shading:**

Right click anywhere within the table and select `Borders and Shading`

Switch to the `Shading` tab

Set the following:

`Fill` to `No Color`
`Patterns` -> `Style` to `Clear`
`Apply to` to `Table`

Click `OK`

[image]

**To remove all the formatting applied to the text:**

Right click anywhere within the table and select `Select` -> `Table`

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to clear all formatting

Comment: Doesn't work. That only does one table at a time. I tried selecting whole document and it the ctrl+space *does* effect the whole document text style but doesn't fix background color